# Разные значения в Settings при запуске из под студии и отдельно

Tags: c#, settings

Всем доброго времени суток.

Программирую в VS 2010, C#. Для сохранения настроек пользуюсь встроенным классом Settings. В Settings создаю настройку, присваиваю начальное значение, Scope - User.
Записываю туда значение так:

```
Settings.Default.name = "имя";
Settings.Default.Save();
```

Ну и считываю

```
String name = Settings.Default.name;
```

Все отлично работает НО:

- если запускать приложение из под студии, то будет одно значение (недефолтное);
- если запускать .exe файл, то значение опять таки отличается. Такое ощущение, что в разных режимах запуска данные сохраняются в разные файлы.

Это все конечно не очень критично, но жутко мешает отлаживать приложение. Собственно вопрос, как мне заставить VS и исполняемый exe использовать один и тот же файл?

Answer (score 4):

[Settings.setting gives the different values in Debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469904)

Comment: Спасибо, это то я понял, а как мне изменить чтобы в режиме отладки были те же значения? Я так понял при отладке запускает доп. процесс "NameApp".vshost.exe и он создает свой config файл.

Comment: читайте в том же ответе: "You can disable this strange behviour by selecting in your Project Properties - Debug - uncheck Enable Visual Studio Hosting Process."

Comment: Спасибо, уже нашел